# How can I change background of a website in sequence of array using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, background-color

I want it to change color in sequence too. The function should be able to change the background color in the array given, in a specific millisecond each. background will be blue, then after 1 second, yellow, after 1 second, pink.. until the end array of color.

```
bg_changer(colors_TO_change_In_Sequence , 1000);

   var colors_TO_change_In_Sequence = ["blue", "yellow", "pink", "black", "white", "green", "purple", "red", "orange"];

    function bg_changer( color_array , millisecond) {
      $(body).css("background-color", color_array[i]   );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** for  function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

```js
var colors_TO_change_In_Sequence = ["blue", "yellow", "pink", "black", "white", "green", "purple", "red", "orange"];
bg_changer(colors_TO_change_In_Sequence, 1000);

function bg_changer(color_array, millisecond) {
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#change').css("background-color", color_array[(i++) % color_array.length]);
  }, millisecond);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="change">Change color</div>
```

Comment: Why doesn't for loop(..) { $('#change').css("background-color", color_array[(i++)) } work? Whereas [(i++) % color_array.length] works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446072/how-to-setinterval-in-javascript-object-literal-function-to-change-the-backgroun

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

```js
function colorLoop(target, interval, colors){
  // registers the next color's index
  var next = 0;
  function nextColor(){
     // update the div's style
     target.style["background-color"] = colors[next];
     // Goes to next color in the colors' list. Uses modulo to loop.
     next = (next + 1) % colors.length;
  }
  // launch the interval
  setInterval(nextColor, interval);
  // init
  nextColor();
}

colorLoop(
  // the target dom element
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
  // the change interval in ms
  1000,
  // the colors
  ["blue", "yellow", "pink", "black", "white", "green", "purple", "red", "orange"]
);
```

```css
body {
  transition: 400ms;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446072/how-to-setinterval-in-javascript-object-literal-function-to-change-the-backgroun